# react-s-alert, alerts won't popup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor-blaze, trello

So i got a meteor setup with a trello like GUI, based on blaze but with react components and i want to use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s-alert for showing some popups (feel free to suggest react alternatives).

So i did this, inside a header bar inside `client/components/main/header.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Alert from 'react-s-alert';

import 'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-default.css';
import 'react-s-alert/dist/s-alert-css-effects/slide.css';

...

Template.header.events({
  'click .js-create-board': Popup.open('createBoard'),
  'click .js-alert'() {
      Alert.info('Test message')
    },
});
```

But when the function is called, nothing happens..

Anyone can help?

Comment: Same issue, did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: No, i switched to https://github.com/themeteorchef/bert

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't added its initializer component in your main component.
Place sAlert component in your main app renderer component also.

```
<Alert stack={{limit: 3}} />
```